# Getting a color gradient between two colors with variable number

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of objects with a Color property. The List may have any number of items ranging from 10 to 4000. I want the Color property of first item to be green and the last item to be red. And all the in between items should get the colors in between red and green (gradient) based on their position (earliest more green and later more red. The following code works only if the list count is less than 255. It returns all white color if the list size exceeds 255

```
           Color start = Colors.White;
            Color end = Colors.Green;
            int steps = lstTag.Count;
            int stepA = ((end.A - start.A) / (steps - 1));
            int stepR = ((end.R - start.R) / (steps - 1));
            int stepG = ((end.G - start.G) / (steps - 1));
            int stepB = ((end.B - start.B) / (steps - 1));

            int i = 0;
            foreach (ArgsData data in lstTag)
            {
                var a = byte.Parse((start.A + (stepA * i)).ToString());
                var r = byte.Parse((start.R + (stepR * i)).ToString());
                var g = byte.Parse((start.G + (stepG * i)).ToString());
                var b = byte.Parse((start.B + (stepB * i)).ToString());
                data.ColorCode = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));

                i++;
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah so calculate the differences between the three colors, and increment or decrement them by the appropriate amount for each step?

Comment: As explained earlier, the list may return more than 255 (around 4000) records.

Comment: Then work with floats, not ints.